# TileList custom ImageCell, buttons/sprites on each image

Tags: actionscript-3, tilelist

Hi im trying to add some buttons or sprites on each of **TileList** items, i even made my own **ImageCell** class and inject some code that adds sprite on each image but it is not clickable - all clicks are reffering to *"object MyImageCell"* not that specific sprite, is there a solution for this or any other way for adding some content on TileList items?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the some problem as I met.In your MyImageCell class add this property:`this.mouseChildren = true;`
Hope this can help.